# Dell Powerdge840 2.4GHz 64 bit quad core

Tags: dell

I am having an issue, where I have changed the boot order to cdrom and turned off hd boot all together and still my system is unable to detect Ubuntu and claims, no boot device found.

**Some additional information:**

When this same cd is inserted and dell is booted into win 2003 server (which is what is installed on this machine), it detects the cd drive but not the cd at all (keeps asking me to insert disc)
I have also created a bootable flash drive using LinuxLive USB creator and when this is selected in boot order again am told no boot device detected.
I was speaking to dell and they suggested perhaps there are no drivers on the actual Ubuntu installation for the hardware on this Dell and hence the failure of this dell to detect the Ubuntu cd.

Now, I don't know too much about computers, but this last bit confused me a bit. If the system detects the hardware (when it is booting it sees the cd rom and in bios it sees when the flash drive is connected), then shouldn't it be able to read what is on those drives? However, if there is some firmware or software install that needs to happen, could someone please tell me where to find the correct drivers for Ubuntu and dell poweredge to work together?

Shall I be installing the desktop version or the server edition, also, 32 bit or 64 bit?

Answer (score 0):

From the Dell PowerEdge 840 manuals:

Your system supports the following operating systems:

• Microsoft Windows ServerTM 2003, Standard Edition and Web Edition

• Microsoft Windows Server 2003, Standard Edition 64-Bit

• Red Hat® Enterprise Linux ES (version 3) for Intel x86

• Red Hat Enterprise Linux ES (version 4) for Intel x86

• Red Hat Enterprise Linux ES (version 4) for Intel Extended Memory 64 Technology (Intel EM64T)
• SUSE® Linux Enterprise Server 9 (Service Pack 2 or later) for Intel EM64T

Therefore this is not a Ubuntu-related question - sorry!